# Double sharp notation - why should i use it?

Tags: notation, accidentals

From wiki:

> **Double sharp** Raises the pitch of a note by two chromatic semitones. Usually used when the note to modify is already sharpened by the key signature

If I write a D note in a D Major key and I want to use a double sharp, why not write an E note instead?

I am confused about why to use double sharps at all.

Comment: 1) D and E are not always the same pitch. 2) Sometimes you need a D instead of an E to correctly spell something. For example, a **G♯+** chord does not contain an E, but a D for the fifth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're in the key of, say, B major, and we need a B augmented chord. That means the 5th of B needs sharpening. Thus, F# now becomes Fx (F##). Yes, on a lot of (12edo) instruments, it's the same note, same place as G. But note (sic) that there's no G nat. diatonically in key B, and that's not the note that gets changed anyway - it's F#. In any case, writing Gnat. would still incur an extra accidental, so why not do it correctly?

You quote writing an E note in the key of D, instead of Dx. In D, it would be very rare to need to double sharp a D note. Generally, a double sharp is used when an *already sharpened* note needs to go up a semitone - and still retain its original letter name - so it would make sense when talking about the interval it makes with preceding and succeeding notes.

Comment: @LoveIsHere - double accidentals generally occur when building augmented chords in sharp keys (double sharps), or diminished chords in flat keys (double flats). There is an exact algorithm for determining where, although I don't know it offhand.

Comment: @Tim considering David Bowling's comment under the main quesiton, is it possile that a F## actually isn't the same pitch as a G?hat is, it's not the same frequency, owing to the not-quite-100% spot-on way that Western scales divide an octave up? (eg a 5th isn't a 'true' 5th)? Please forgive my terminology; I'm not too well read with music theory.

Comment: @user2808054 - hence my ' (12edo)', when the octave is equally divided into 12, as in most modern pianos. Yes, Gnat and Fx may well be played *slightly* differently by, say, string players, however, that factor didn't really crop up from the question, so didn't need addressing here.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason: simplicity of notation.  Say you have a piece in Bb, and somewhere along the way there's an E-natural followed with an E-flat.  Rather than write "naturalsign-E ; flat-sign-E",  it's much easier for the performer to read "double-sharp-D; E (defaulting to Eb due to key signature)".

#### ETA

Thanks to Milo (apparently back from the Tollbooth) for a better example -- playing in   G# minor to see Fx moving to G#

Comment: Thanks but lets say that after all that we need to play d natrual again there would be a need to asign a natrual sine again in the d isnt it?

Comment: @LoveIsHere yes, that's true.  When music gets seriously chromatic, there's gonna be headaches.

Comment: Wouldn't say it's much easier to read. About the same, I'd say. And it may go against what the note actually should be. I've seen too many e.g. C7b9 written with C# as the 'flat 9'. It's wrong, and confusing - to me at least...

Comment: Carl, I disagree; I'm with @Tim. In the context of a key signature of two flats, an E (natural) would be fairly common. Double-sharps would be bizarre and thus hard to read.

Comment: An Fb moving to Eb might be okay, but Dx moving to Eb would be confusing, given that one would see an upwards motion in the score representing a decrease in pitch. I would more expect, for instance, in G# minor to see Fx moving to G#.